# How to nest in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list comp like the following:

```
import subprocess

last_logins = [i.split(' ', 1)[0] for i in subprocess.check_output('last').split('\n') if 'reboot' not in i]
print("The last five logins were: {0}".format(', '.join(last_logins[0:5])))
```

And it returns:

```
The last five logins were: vagrant, vagrant, vagrant, vagrant, vagrant
```

How do I nest a sub-loop that keeps a tally of the users, and, in this case, returns:

```
The last five logins were: vagrant: 2x, some_other_user: 3x
```

Yes, it's ugly and the comprehension line is too long. (I'm open to critiques/suggestions for writing clearer code). But I'd also like to find out the right way to nest loops in (list) comprehensions.

Comment: What's wrong with a normal for loop?

Comment: Nothing. Just curious about how to use list comprehensions/one-liners as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

last_logins = ['Vagrant', 'Vagrant', 'Some Other User', 'Vagrant', 'Some Other User']

last_five_stats = Counter(last_logins[:5])
print("The last five logins were: {0}".format(', '.join("{0}: {1}x".format(user, count) for user, count in last_five_stats.items())))
```

Prints:

```
The last five logins were: Vagrant: 3x, Some Other User: 2x
```

This though would be a bit nicer with [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (Python 3.6+):

```
last_five_stats = (f"{user}: {count}x" for user, count in Counter(last_logins[:5]).items())
print(f"The last five logins were: {', '.join(last_five_stats)}")
```